# Need to write specific columns in output file using tcl

Tags: tcl

I am trying to read a file with 5 columns( separated using space delimiter)

```
#text  tag    x     y     data_lay

bad    bad1   10.0  10.0   L1

good   goodn  13.0  11.0   L1
```

And trying to output the specific columns with a prefix on the first column in a new file. Output format should be like following

```
 Add_obj bad  10.0 10.0 L1

 Add_obj good 13.0 11.0 L1
```

I tried the following but has been unsuccessful in getting the anticipated output. Here, is the snippet of the code

```
set fp [open [lindex $argv 0] r]

set colData {}

while {[gets $fp line]>=0} {

    if {[llength $line] ==4 } {
   
        set colData [split $line “ “]
   
         puts “Add_obj [lindex $colData 0] [lindex $colData 2] [lindex $colData 3] [lindex $colData 4]”
   
    }
}

close $fp
```

Could you please help with a sample code?
Thanks.

Comment: What output did you get? "llength $line" will not be 4, since $line is not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There's no need to split $line by a space.  As long as $line can be used as a proper list, then you can use `lindex` on $line.
2. I think you want to print only when `llength` is 5 (not 4).
3. I noticed in your sample code that there are non-ascii double quotes `“` and `”`.     You need to have regular double quotes `"`.

```
set fp [open a.txt]

while {[gets $fp line]>=0} {

    if {[llength $line] == 5 } {
        # Skip header?
        if {[string match "#*" $line]} {
            continue
        }
        puts "Add_obj [lindex $line 0] [lindex $line 2] [lindex $line 3] [lindex $line 4]"
   
    }
}

close $fp
```

You might want to also print a formatted string, prepared with the `format` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. Most of them (1-3 ) are typos as I have pasted the sample code using mobile. 

Regards,

Comment: If you can't trust that the input data is a valid list, then use `regexp` to extract the sequences of non-whitespace: `set fields [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line]`